# Java объединение WAV-файлов

Tags: java

У меня есть метод, который объединяет несколько wav файлов в один:

```
public Path getWavFile(List<String> audioFiles, String outputFileName) {

    File folder = new File(appProperties.getResponseFolder());
    if (!folder.exists()) folder.mkdirs();
    File file = new File(folder.toURI().getPath() + outputFileName + ".wav");

    Vector v = new Vector();
    try {
        long fileLength = 0;
        for (Path path : getPaths(audioFiles)) {
            log.info("getWavFile {}", path.toFile());
            fileLength += AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(path.toFile()).getFrameLength();
            log.info("fileLength {}", fileLength);
            v.add(new FileInputStream(path.toFile()));
        }

        log.info("v.elements() {}", v.size());

        Enumeration e = v.elements();

        SequenceInputStream sis = new SequenceInputStream(e);

        log.info("AudioFormat {}", AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(getFilePathString(audioFiles.get(0)))).getFormat().toString());

        AudioInputStream appendedFiles =
                new AudioInputStream(
                        sis,
                        AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(getFilePathString(audioFiles.get(0)))).getFormat(),
                        fileLength);

        AudioSystem.write(appendedFiles,
                AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE,
                file);

        log.info("Audio file is created: " + file.getAbsolutePath());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.warn(e.toString());
    }
    return file.toPath();
}
```

НО в получившемся файле, в начале каждого присоединенного участка слышен щелчок...

Кто-нибудь сталкивался с таким?

Откуда он берется?

Comment: предположу, что [wav](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAV)-файл содержит заголовок со служебной информацией. Поскольку вы отдаете в `SequenceInputStream` список `FileInputStream`, эти заголовки попадают в результат. Попробуйте передать список из результатов `AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(..)`.

Comment: Да, так и сделал.
Спасибо за ваш отклик